# How to fix create node index error in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, nestjs, neo4j-apoc

- neo4j version: 5.7.0
- apoc: 5.7.2
- GDSL: 2.3.6

I have a `nestjs` app using a neo4j DB, in which I want to create a index like this:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex(
  "FTS_Person_Company_fullName",
  ["Person", "Company"],
  ["fullName"],
  {analyzer: "standard-folding", eventually_consistent: "true"})
```

but I get this error:

> Neo4jError: There is no procedure with the name  `db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.

I tried to change the version of neo4j but that did not help to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In neo4j 5.x, the Cypher language directly supports [creating fulltext indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-full-text-search/#indexes-fulltext-search-create-and-configure).

For example, in your case:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX FTS_Person_Company_fullName 
FOR (n:Person|Company)
ON EACH [n.fullName]
OPTIONS {
  indexConfig: {
    `fulltext.analyzer`: "standard-folding",
    `fulltext.eventually_consistent`: true
  }
}
```

Comment: i have another problem, i do SHOW INDEXES and i see in that list this 'FTS_Person_Company_fullName' but when i do CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("FTS_Person_Company_fullName") i get another error like Failed to invoke procedure `db.index.fulltext.queryNodes`: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no such fulltext schema index: FTS_Person_fullName

Comment: Are you passing the right index name? The error is not showing ''FTS_Person_Company_fullName''.